# Why, when touching the Android screen it does nothing?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is the MainActivity.java

```
package com.test.webservertest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.AndroidRuntimeException;
import android.util.Xml;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.util.EncodingUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
    public static MainActivity currentActivity;
    TextToSpeech mTts;
    private String targetURL;
    private String urlParameters;
    private Button btnClick;
    private String clicking = "clicked";
    private final String[] ipaddresses = new String[2];
    private final Integer[] ipports = new Integer[2];
    private TextView text;
    private Socket socket;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //setContentView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, null));

        /*ipaddresses[0] = "10.0.0.3";
        ipaddresses[1] = "10.0.0.2";
        ipports[0] = 8098;
        ipports[1] = 8088;*/

        //addListenerOnButton();
        currentActivity = this;
        initTTS();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        /*btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkipbutton);

        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                try
                {

                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    text.setText("Connection Failed");
                }
            }
        });*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Dispatch onStart() to all fragments.  Ensure any created loaders are
     * now started.
     */   

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        TextToSpeechServer.main(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void initTTS() {
        Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if(resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                mTts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new OnInitListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInit(int i) {

                        if(i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                            int result = mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                            if(result == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE
                                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE) {
                                mTts.setPitch(1);
                                mTts.speak(textforthespeacch, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    public static String textforthespeacch = "";
    public static void TextToSpeak(String text) {
        textforthespeacch = text;
    }

    private boolean is_start = true;
    public class SingleTouchEventView extends View {
        private Paint paint = new Paint();
        private Path path = new Path();
        private Path circlePath = new Path();

        public SingleTouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);

            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
            canvas.drawPath(circlePath, paint);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();

            float lastdownx = 0;
            float lastdowny = 0;

            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                    circlePath.addCircle(eventX, eventY, 50, Path.Direction.CW);
                    lastdownx = eventX;
                    lastdowny = eventY;

                    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            byte[] response = null;
                            if (is_start == true)
                            {
                                response = Get("http://10.0.0.2:8098/?cmd=start");
                                is_start = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                               response = Get("http://10.0.0.2:8098/?cmd=stop");
                                is_start = true;
                            }

                            if (response!=null)
                            {
                                String a = null;
                                try
                                {
                                    a = new String(response,"UTF-8");
                                    textforthespeacch = a;
                                    MainActivity.currentActivity.initTTS();
                                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info(a);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    t.start();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // nothing to do
                    circlePath.reset();   
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }    
            // Schedules a repaint.
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

    private byte[] Get(String urlIn)
    {
        URL url = null;

        String urlStr = urlIn;

        if (urlIn!=null)
            urlStr=urlIn;

        try
        {
            url = new URL(urlStr);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try
        {

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            byte[] buf=new byte[10*1024];
            int szRead = in.read(buf);

            byte[] bufOut;   
            if (szRead==10*1024)
            {
                throw new AndroidRuntimeException("the returned data is bigger than 10*1024.. we don't handle it..");
            }
            else
            {
                bufOut = Arrays.copyOf(buf, szRead);
            }
            return bufOut;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (urlConnection!=null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

It was working fine. Maybe I need to enable something on my Android device?

My Android device is connected now to the PC via USB and working fine.

When I'm running my program in debug mode and touch the screen it never stop on:

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
            float eventX = event.getX();
```

I added a break point on the line: `float eventX = event.getX();`
But touching the screen does nothing.

Comment: This is my entire code of MainActivity.java maybe someone can look and find what is wrong ? http://pastebin.com/YJk9xhsy

Comment: This is the file styles.xml code: http://pastebin.com/9c5DpcJ9

Comment: And last the file View.class maybe something changed ther: http://pastebin.com/NQ1dRGXw

Answer (score 0):

You are not at all registering the OnTouchListener. First register OnTouchListener using anonymousclass or just implements it in your class

From your code you need the listener for this SingleTouchEventView view. Just add "`implements View.OnTouchListenter`" for the class. Because you have already overridden onTouch method in your code.

Comment: How do i register ? If i try to impements it on my class which is now: public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity so if i change it to public class MainActivity extends implements View.OnTouchListener then i need to change the class to be abstract. And if i want to register it inside the onCreate ?

Comment: which view you want the touchlistener in your class. register it for the specific view

Comment: I did: public class MainActivity implements View.OnTouchListenter but getting error on OnTouchListenter cannot resolve symbol on...So i clicked Alt + Enter and did create interface and it did create it on the file View.class but it didn't solve the error.

Comment: If i\m adding abstract: public abstract class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener then it fix the error but then when running the program it crash and close the program.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your style.xml when you remove "Extends ActionbarActivity"!
Check this [change appTheme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30846924/4897420)

Comment: In the styles.xml i have: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> and i tried to change now the class to public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity and before it i tried to change it to only public class MainActivity still not working when touching the screen it dosen't do anything.

Comment: It's about your crash situation not about clicklistener. If you remove "extends actionbar acrivity" you need that